# how to prevent TableViewCell from reseting view when scrolling (reusing the cells)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm creating a `TableView` with custom cells that is supposed to have two labels and a download button. Upon tapping on the download button, the button is removed and a `ProgressView` is placed. The `ProgressView` is supposed to display the amount of a file download. Until here everything works fine, the problem is that when i scroll and for example the first cell of the table is out of the visible frame, the download `ProgressView` is reset and when i scroll to that cell again, the download button is subviewed instead.

**Note**: the whole thing is supposed to look like Apple Podcast app.

Comment: paste your code -> straight forward answer is don't reuse cells.
when you initiating them .

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct approach.
The correct approach is having the datasource hold the progress of the downloads , whenever a cell reaches prepare for reuse function - reset it to the initial state (download button and no progress view) and when dequeueing read the progress from the datasource and set it again.

Another thing you can do (which is practically what you asked) - is always create new cells instead of dequeuing cells and creating only if not getting a cell back. This should eliminate the re-use of cells - but with a big table and heavy table cells might not be the correct approach.